# How to change the direction of focus in ios App to be right to left?

Tags: ios, objective-c, right-to-left, uiaccessibility

I am responsible for the  integration of accessibility for an iOS application.

And I am having difficulty in changing the **focus direction** from LTR to RTL.

How can i do it in Xcode?

Comment: What do you mean by direction of focus?

Comment: @SahebRoy When a user with disability need to reach to a components of the app (like buttons\links\inputs...) only by focus them, with sweeping with the finger to right\left. I need to change that the focus will be start frrm ight and not from the left.o

Comment: What do u mean by focusing on them?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to create an array for accessibile items.
for eg: i have 2 outlets say: `leftbutton` and `rightbutton`.

Then in your `viewDidLoad()` add this:

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification, rightbutton)

self.accessibilityElements = [rightbutton, leftbutton]
```